# Cookies in ASP vnext

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How can i use cookies in ASP MVC 6? I want to set and read cookie variables .

HttpCookie class can't be resolved .

Only the following line works but i couldn't find a way to read the cookie after adding it . 
Response.Cookies.Append("test", "test");

Comment: There's no API to read response cookies

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at how cookies are used in the official MusicStore sample: https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/a7ba4f8ffe5ed23b2a2d55e8e1226e64066a7ada/src/MusicStore/Models/ShoppingCart.cs#L152

```
public string GetCartId(HttpContext context) 
{ 
    var sessionCookie = context.Request.Cookies.Get("Session");
```

Comment: This seems to be outdated as the "Get" method no longer exists.  Has anyone got an up to date version of this? Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The answer from Victor Hurdugaci applies to pre-RC2 releases and this was changed a little bit, so here is the current (and hopefully final) stage:

You set the cookie on the Response by:

```
HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("key", "value");
```

Here cookies is an `IResponseCookies`. You can only write to it.

This will be then sent to the browser.

You can read the cookies sent by the browser on the Request object:

```
HttpContext.Request.Cookies["key"]
```

Here Cookies is an `IRequestCookieCollection`, so you can also read from it.