# error on HttpCookie in mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies

I try to set my cookie up to my website but when I write Http Cookie into the code,

my code looks like this:

```
HttpCookie StudentCookies = new HttpCookie("StudentCookies");
StudentCookies.Value = 1;
Response.Cookies.Add(StudentCookies);
```

error are:

> The type or namespace name 'HttpCookie' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   TestMVCLagerSystem.DNX 4.5.1
>
> 'Response' does not contain a definition for
>   'Cookies' TestMVCLagerSystem.DNX 4.5.1

i have try to looke here:

[Using Cookie in Asp.Net Mvc 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128507/using-cookie-in-asp-net-mvc-4)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cookies in ASP vnext](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29064785/cookies-in-asp-vnext)

Comment: Looking at the error, it looks like you are using ASP 5/MVC 6. Check the question I flagged as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this instead:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(StudentCookies);
```

Both HttpCookie and HttpContext belong to System.Web reference (using System.Web;)

(edited to show code formatting)